# What event does AWS s3 CLI "cp" and "sync" trigger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I have lambda functions that run off of s3 events. I'm using aws-cli to move items into s3. I'm not sure what triggers when you perform a 'sync' and a file is actually added by the sync.

I *think* that s3 **cp** triggers a "put" event (ObjectCreatedByPut), and if the file is large enough it triggers a "multipart upload" event (ObjectCreatedByCompleteMultipartUpload). I don't believe it triggers a "copy" event, even though cp is in the command.

I don't think s3 **sync** triggers either of these. But I'm not 100% sure. I've tried reading through their docs but I'm not finding specific answers. I'm trying to pick up each event by a specific lambda function, so I'm just having trouble with what the **sync** triggers, if it triggers *anything* at all.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to respond to an object being uploaded to S3, regardless of the API used, use `s3:ObjectCreated:*`.

Answer (score 5):

`aws s3 cp` could trigger a `s3:ObjectCreated:Copy` if both of your src and dst are S3 buckets.

`aws s3 sync` will

1. run a `aws s3 cp` when the [Comparator](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/1b276f68fbe3511d795a2e09e2e90688c02c1bec/awscli/customizations/s3/comparator.py#L20) determines that the file needs to be uploaded or downloaded. This will trigger a `s3:ObjectCreated:Put` or `s3:ObjectCreated:Copy` or `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload` depending on the file size, src and dst.
2. run a `aws s3 rm` when the [Comparator](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/1b276f68fbe3511d795a2e09e2e90688c02c1bec/awscli/customizations/s3/comparator.py#L20) determines that the file needs to be removed from the S3 bucket. This will

   - trigger a `s3:ObjectRemoved:DeleteMarkerCreated` if the status of the S3 bucket versioning is `Enabled` or `Suspended`.
   - trigger a `s3:ObjectRemoved:Delete` if the status of the S3 bucket versioning is `Disabled`.

Let me know if you have any further questions :)

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to create Lambda Function (or preferably StepFunctions State machine) that would be triggered after a `aws sync` got completed. How could I identify some sort "_Sync Event Completed_" state ? Is there a way for that ?

Comment: @Smithfield were you able to figure out how to do that?

Comment: @alayor I guess the easiest way is to execute some sort of command after the `aws sync` in your bash script.